# How to add timer to a blackberry application

Tags: java, blackberry

Sir i am developing an application in blackberry.Its like a test with some questions,at the end of the test result is being displayed.Nw i want to add a timer at the top,so that when the test starts,till a user finishes a test,the time will be displayed at the top of the screen.So i want to add a timer for that.Time should be in the format of 00:00,& it will keep on increasing till the user finishes a test.Can anyone help me with the code for timer.